# example of a convergent series that $\lim \sup |\frac{z_{n+1}}{z_n} | > 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, limsup-and-liminf, conditional-convergence

Let $(z_n) \subset \mathbb C$, with $z_n \neq 0$. It's known that if $\lim \sup |\frac{z_{n+1}}{z_n} | < 1$, so $\sum |z_n|$ converges, then $\sum z_n$ converges.

Can I find an example of a convergent series that $\lim \sup |\frac{z_{n+1}}{z_n} | > 1$ ?

Comment: How about $z_n = 1/n^2$ if $n$ is even, and $z_n = 1/n^3$ if $n$ is odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the sequence
\begin{align*}
z_n&=\begin{cases}
5 \left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}&n\text{ odd}\\
\left(\frac12\right)^n&n\text{ even}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Let the terms be
$$1,2,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{32},\dots.$$